# setting up a vhost alias with a wildcard for domain and document root - doc root not parsed correctly

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, documentroot, namevirtualhost

I only have a fuzzy idea of the correct terminology to use in this question so please feel free to help me by clarifying it.

I have a vhost setup. The idea is that I want a wildcard to route all requests for `root.TERM.lh` to a `/TERM/` document root.

The setup below recognises the domains fine and routes them accordingly, but it doesn't translate the %1 in the document root to TERM. For eg the Apache error log tells me that for a request to root.mywebsite.lh it's attempting to route to `/Users/hollsk/Dev/websites/%1`, so it's interpreting it as a literal string.

Is my syntax incorrect, or am I missing some module?

```
NameVirtualHost *
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName root.%1.lh
    ServerAlias root.%1.lh
    DocumentRoot /Users/hollsk/Dev/websites/%1/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Take a look at mod_macro for Apache, if I understand your question correctly, it'll allow you to do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My syntax was subtly incorrect.

```
NameVirtualHost *
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName root.%2.lh
    ServerAlias root.%2.lh
    DocumentRoot /Users/hollsk/Dev/websites/%2/
</VirtualHost>
```

Note the `%2` instead of `%1` - still not sure why `%1` was being intepreted literally (instead of as the string `root`, which is what I'd expect), but changing to the correct handle fixed the problem in any case.

Answer (score 3):

This style of configuration requires using an add-on module, not the core virtual hosting directives.

See VirtualDocumentRoot here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html

Comment: Ta. The module was already enabled, and the problem was my syntax. Upvoting as the answer would help somebody else without the module switched on, though.